# Cut linestings at nearest point junctions

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Using the "function to cut linestings and multilinestrings at nearest point junctions" found in chapter 11 of the book *PostGIS in Action* by Regina Obe and Leo Hsu (Second Edition)

It returns this error when running in PgAdmin 4:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 40:    END IF;
            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1064
```

Code lines around line 40:

```
        ELSE
         var_lset[j] := kutt(var_lset[j],var_pset[i])
        END IF;
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is simple, missing semi-colon on the end of this line:-

```
  kutt(var_lset[j],var_pset[i]);
```

It has nothing to do with Postgis being installed

Comment: Thnx! Any idea why it still won't run in SQL Shell (psql)

ERROR: type geometry does not exist

Comment: That is down to Postgis not being installed ;-) Try CREATE EXTENSION postgis;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't installed PostGIS in the database.

Run

```
Create extension PostGIS;
```

before creating the function